# Nested LinearLayout does not align to parent ScrollView?

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have a fragment with two horizontal Buttons (**yellow** = *fragment_test_button_container*) at the bottom of my fragment. I would like to use the remaining area (**red** = *fragment_test_scrollview*) for a ScrollView [image: fragment_test] It is reuiqred that my ScrollView consist of one layout (**turquoise** = *fragment_test_check*) only . This can then in turn have further layouts, as you can see in the attached fragment_test.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.TestFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_test_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_test_button_container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".84"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_test_check"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_test_front_photo_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".28"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_test_front_photo_title"
                    style="@style/myapp_MediumTextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/myapp_test_fragment_textview_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:text="@string/fragment_test_front_photo_title_text" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_test_front_photo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_test_back_photo_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".28"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_test_back_photo_title"
                    style="@style/myapp_MediumTextStyle"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/myapp_test_fragment_textview_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:text="@string/fragment_test_back_photo_title_text" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_test_back_photo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- ADDITIONAL DATA -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_test_data_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".34"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingStart="24dp"
                android:paddingEnd="24dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_test_value1_label"
                        style="@style/myapp_MediumTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text=„Value1^“ />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_test_value1_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_test_value2_label"
                        style="@style/myapp_MediumTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text=„Value2“ />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_test_value2_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_test_value3_label"
                        style="@style/myapp_MediumTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="Ausstellungsdatum" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_test_value3_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_test_button_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_test_scrollview">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_test_back_button"
            style="@style/myapp_ContinueBackButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/myapp_continueBackButton_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/myapp_colorPrimary"
            android:text=„back“
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_test_next_button"
            style="@style/myapp_ContinueBackButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/myapp_continueBackButton_height"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dpVerySmall"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/myapp_colorPrimary"
            android:text="continue"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But my turqoise (fragment_test_check) area is not aligned fully with the blue area (fragment_test_scrollview), altough I wrote match_parent. I would like the heigth of turqoise area as the blue area.

**Why is my turqoise area dangling in half the blue area?**

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:fillViewport="true"` in your `ScrollView`.

`fillViewport` stretches the content's height to the viewport's boundaries, when set `true`. In simple words, `fillViewport` decides whether the nested contents of the layout should match the parent's boundaries or not. Thus, to make the nested layout match the parent's boundary, set `fillViewport` to true

Moreover, the `layout_gravity` for nested components should be 1 or whatsoever you define in `weight_sum` of parent layout, whereas in your case it is 0.90 .

Comment: Please provide an explanation why this code might work.

Comment: Please accept and upvote my answer, if it resolves your issue.